# Pros and cons of converting weekly to daily data

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, econometrics, macroeconomics

I am trying to forecast an economic variable called the "yield spread" in python. Among the variables in my dataset, two of them are measured on a weekly basis. These are:

unemployment insurance claims (ui_claims),
total assets held by the Fed (total_assets)

The majority of the other variables are monthly such as:
federal funds rate (ffr),
Consumer Price Index (cpi)

Others have daily frequency such as:
TED spread (ted),
term premium

My question is - is it ok to convert weekly into daily data for time series forecasting? I could use cubic spline interpolation, but then the downside is that it would just be making up lot of data. So, I was wondering what the costs and benefits of converting would be.

Comment: Why convert this data at all? It is perfectly legitimate and reasonable to have data with mixed temporality in a model.

Comment: if I don't convert then there will be numerous NA values in the dataset if I merge the monthly and weekly variables in one data frame.

Comment: Then that becomes a question for Stack Overflow or an R community Q&A blog, how do you merge daily and weekly data without creating 'numerous NA values in the dataset.'

Comment: @user332577 when one creates a time series model for daily data that includes exogenous covariates (eg. ARIMAX), they are typically required to specify the *daily* values of the covariates. Are you suggesting the OP uses an algorithm that does not have this restriction? If so, perhaps you could suggest some specific options, as I'm not sure how one would implement what you suggest.

Comment: @RyanVolpi The OPs question was not about ARIMAX, it was about merging data with differing temporality. This is not a statistical question nor is it algorithmic. You seem to be suggesting that interpolating weekly data into daily is a desirable solution. I couldn't disagree more as it would introduce false and inaccurate variance. The easiest solution would not be a merge by date but, rather, creating a *weekly* variable in both datasets and merge by that variable. If that includes controlling for the year, then do so. Most software would accept that merge and populate all records with no NAs.

Comment: Actually, my question is about the feasibility of doing ARIMAX with daily data. I was wondering if it is statistically (or theoretically) correct? What biases or other problems would it generate? I know its possible to merge datasets of different frequencies, and I can do that in python. Hence, I asked the question here in StackExchange, and not in StackOverflow. But thank you for your response @user332577